# Как вставить в таблицу данные если данные могут быть а могут отсутствовать условие where mysql [SOLVED]

Tags: mysql, sql, json, join

У мня есть таблица, которая хранит параметры из json:

```
drop table if exists json_params;
    create table json_params
    select city_name,
           country_name,
           countryName,
           ifnull(date_from,
                  (select cast(min(payment_date) as date) from payment)),
           ifnull(date_to,
                  (select cast(max(payment_date) as date) from payment))
    from json_table(jsonText, '$'
            columns (
              date_from date path '$.date.date_from',
              date_to date path '$.date.date_to',
              nested path '$.cities[*]' columns (
                 city_name varchar(50) path '$.city_name',
                 country_name varchar(50) path '$.country.country_name'
              ),
              nested path '$.countries[*]' columns (
                 countryName varchar(50) path '$.country_name'
              )
            )) c;
```

Это либо город со страной, либо страна, либо ничего из переисленного, так же с датой, только если дата отсутствует, подставляется минимальная и максимальная из другой таблицы, поэтому если вдруг json пришел совершенно пустой, в таблице будет как минимум одна запись - `date_from, date_to` + на месте остальных колонок будет `null`

Json:

```
'{
  "date":{
    "date_from":"2020-01-01",
    "date_to":"2021-03-09"
  },
  "cities":[
    {
      "city_name":"Minsk",
      "country": {
        "country_name":"Belarus"
      }
    },
    {
      "city_name":"Grodno",
      "country": {
        "country_name":"Belarus"
      }
    }
  ]
}'
```

Json предсавляет собой как бы "фильтр" - его мне необходимо соединить с существующими таблицами городов и стран так - если указан город, соединить по нему, если указана страна (`"countries":[...]`)  - соединиь по сране, если ничего не указано - вставить в таблицу просто все города что есть, но так же вставить и `date_from + date_to` - и главное сделать это все в одном запросе. Вот таблица, которая в будущем будет представлять данные для фильтра:

```
drop table if exists filter_params;
    create table filter_params(
        city_id mediumint unsigned,
        city_name varchar(50),
        date_from date,
        date_to date
    );
```

Я пыталась сделать так, но он тем не менее выбирает все записи из табицы городов (а такое должно происходить только при отсутствии городов либо стран в json):

```
insert into filter_params(city_id, city_name, date_from, date_to)
    select
           c.city_id,
           c.city_name,
           cj.date_from as cj_from,
           cj.date_to as cj_to
    from city c
    join country c2 on c2.country_id = c.country_id
    left join json_params jp  on
          c.city_name = jp.city_name and
          c2.country_name = jp.country_name or
          c2.country_name = jp.countryName
    cross join (select city_name, date_from, date_to
                from json_params
                limit 1) cj
    where jp.city_name    is not null and
          jp.country_name is not null and
          countryName     is null     or
          countryName     is not null and
          jp.city_name    is null     and
          jp.country_name is null     or
          jp.city_name    is null     and
          jp.country_name is null     and
          countryName     is null;
```

Необходимо как-то указать в кросс жоине, что, если самая первая запись из таблицы `json_param` окажется пустой, значит и сам джейсон был пустым, а значит необходимо вставить все города, иначе - вставить только те данные, которые есть в `json_param`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Нужно оставить только те, где есть город, либо те, где есть cityName, либо все сразу**
Как это селать?

Попыталась еще так:

```
select
           c.city_id,
           c.city_name,
           countryName,
           jp.city_name as city,
           jp.country_name,
           jp.date_from as jp_from,
           jp.date_to as jp_to,
           cj.date_from as cj_from,
           cj.date_to as cj_to
    from city c
    join country c2 on c2.country_id = c.country_id
    left join json_params jp  on
          c.city_name = jp.city_name and
          c2.country_name = jp.country_name or
          c2.country_name = jp.countryName
    cross join (select city_name, date_from, date_to
                from json_params
                limit 1) cj
    where c.city_name in (select city_name from json_params) or
          c2.country_name in (if((select countryName from json_params limit 1) is null,
                                 (select country_name from country),
                                 (select countryName from json_params)));
```

Но `subquery returns more then 1 row`

Comment: Вы лучше fiddle сделайте - обе таблицы с примером данных (как они получены - ну совершенно пофиг), да покажите требуемый результат с пояснениями.

Answer (score 0):

Долго вы) Ответ:

```
insert into filter_params(city_id, city_name, country_name, date_from, date_to)
    select
           c.city_id,
           c.city_name,
           c2.country_name,
           cj.date_from ,
           cj.date_to
    from city c
    join country c2 on c2.country_id = c.country_id
    left join json_params jp  on
          c.city_name = jp.city_name and
          c2.country_name = jp.country_name or
          c2.country_name = jp.countryName
    cross join (select city_name, countryName, date_from, date_to
                from json_params
                limit 1) cj
    where jp.city_name is not null and
          jp.countryName is null or
          jp.countryName is not null and
          jp.city_name is null or
          cj.city_name is null and
          cj.countryName is null;
```